# seq.Date giving problems

Tags: r

I have recently updated R to version 3.2.3 and now I found a problem using `seq` with dates:

```
date1<-as.POSIXct("2014-01-30 02:00:00")
date2<-as.POSIXct("2014-12-24 11:00:00")
seq(date1,date2,by="month")
#[1] "2014-01-30 02:00:00 CET"  "2014-03-02 02:00:00 CET" 
#[3] NA                         "2014-04-30 02:00:00 CEST"
#[5] "2014-05-30 02:00:00 CEST" "2014-06-30 02:00:00 CEST"
#[7] "2014-07-30 02:00:00 CEST" "2014-08-30 02:00:00 CEST"
#[9] "2014-09-30 02:00:00 CEST" "2014-10-30 02:00:00 CET" 
#[11] "2014-11-30 02:00:00 CET"
```

I don't understand where the `NA` comes from. I have tried on different machines with both the same R version as mine or a previous one and in the place of that `NA` they correctly give `"2014-03-30"`. Furthermore, if I change the year in the dates from 2014 to 2015, no `NAs` are returned!
I guess that during the installation something in my locale was modified but I cannot understand how to fix the problem.
`Sys.getlocale()` returns:

```
"en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

and my system is a Mac Book Pro with Maverick.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Everything seems fine to me. I'm on Ubuntu though.

Comment: Suspicious that DST might be different in your locale. In my printout (running in a locale that is several timezones to the "left" of "CET/CEST), I get a shift to PDT in the third position which is where you are getting your NA. It is a bit puzzling to me that your locale is US yet CET is not a US TZ. Try `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)`

Comment: @42- `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)` gives `"Europe/Rome"`

Answer (score 5):

I was guessing Germany and here's what the situation was in that CET timezone on Mar 30 (a Sunday)

```
http://www.timetemperature.com/utc-converter/utc-20140330-germany-12.html
UTC or GMT Time Germany
Sunday 30th March 2014 00:00:00 Sun 01:00 AM
Sunday 30th March 2014 01:00:00 Sun 03:00 AM*
```

Changing the setting to Italy, I get the same result:

```
UTC or GMT Time Italy
Sunday 30th March 2014 00:00:00 Sun 01:00 AM
Sunday 30th March 2014 01:00:00 Sun 03:00 AM*
```

The key here is to be suspicious of weirdness when the time is in the early morning hours of a Spring or Fall date, or when calculations of intervals crosses such dates. The rules change from year to year, and since countries often do the switch on a Sunday or Saturday morning, the exact dates jump around.

The changes vary by country and in the US they may vary by state or even "sub-state" boundaries: In Washington State in 2014 you find the change happening onhte second Sunday of March:

```
http://www.timetemperature.com/utc-converter/utc-20140309-us-washington+state-12.html
UTC or GMT Time US-Washington State
snipped several times
Sunday 9th March 2014 07:00:00  Sat 11:00 PM
Sunday 9th March 2014 08:00:00  Sun 12:00 AM
Sunday 9th March 2014 09:00:00  Sun 01:00 AM
Sunday 9th March 2014 10:00:00  Sun 03:00 AM*
Sunday 9th March 2014 11:00:00  Sun 04:00 AM*
```

I'm in the same TZ as Washington state. With a Sys.timezone set, one can reproduce the NA, at least on a Mac. The implementation of times and timezones is OS-specific, so it's possible to see variations in how these weirdities get visible:

```
> Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)
[1] "America/Los_Angeles"
> date1<-as.POSIXct("2014-01-09 02:00:00")
> date2<-as.POSIXct("2014-12-09 11:00:00")
> seq(date1,date2,by="month")
 [1] "2014-01-09 02:00:00 PST" "2014-02-09 02:00:00 PST"
 [3] NA                        "2014-04-09 02:00:00 PDT"
 [5] "2014-05-09 02:00:00 PDT" "2014-06-09 02:00:00 PDT"
 [7] "2014-07-09 02:00:00 PDT" "2014-08-09 02:00:00 PDT"
 [9] "2014-09-09 02:00:00 PDT" "2014-10-09 02:00:00 PDT"
[11] "2014-11-09 02:00:00 PST" "2014-12-09 02:00:00 PST"
```

Comment: DST dates are generally different in different timezones.

Comment: I realized that this was one of your points and +1'd your answer. Just thought it might be useful to state this more clearly.

Comment: I still don't totally get it. For me it works fine and the `NA` date in the OP is resolved (correctly) to `"2014-03-30 03:00:00 CEST"`. I'm also from Rome, even if my `Sys.timezone()` gives `NA`. Why OP's R is not able to correctly resolve the date?

Comment: This looks very much like a bug to me.

Comment: If you think this is a bug then you need to decide where you will complain. After reading the help page: `?timezones`, it seems unlikely that complaining to R-Core will be received favorably: "Note that except where replaced, the operation of time zones is an OS service, and even where replaced a third-party database is used and can be updated (see the section on ‘Time zone names’). Incorrect results will never be an R issue, so please ensure that you have the courtesy not to blame R for them."

Answer (score 1):

By inspecting the relevant code in seq.POSIXt there appears that a call to seq with by="month" works as follows

- [some manipulation of the data]
- conversion of data1 & data2 to POSIXlt
- creation of a sequence of months numbers spanning the interval from data1 to data2 (in this case 0,...,11)
- manual update of data1$mon to this sequence of months (and up to this point the dates are all properly handled)
- finally, the resulting dates are converted to POSIXct and here the NA shows up

while the resulting NA is technically correct, since it is trying to convert an invalid date ("2014-01-30 02:00:00 CET", which does not exist) to POSIXct, could the issue be possibly worked around by passing through difftimes? [*]

not sure it is worth, though...

[*] here by difftimes I mean to add the correct number of seconds to the dates instead of just adding the months...